# Subset contents of one file based on contents of another

Tags: python, file, filter

I am trying to subset the contents of one file using the contents of another. File1 contains a single value per line:

```
43
44
101
```

File2 contains two values per line, values are separated by a single space:

```
43 48
43 54
44 12
88 55
101 31
101 56
101 61
```

I would like to filter the contents of File2 based on the contents of File1, such that if the first value in any line of File2 matches any value in File1, the line from File2 will be printed to a new file. Some lines in File2 should not be included in the new file (value does not exist in File1), and some values from File1 have multiple entries in File2. The output should look like this:

```
43 48
43 54
44 12
101 31
101 56
101 61
```

I've been trying to work through the code for this task in Python. I am relatively new to this language, but here is some of what I have tried so far:

```
output=open("new_file.txt","a") 

for i in file2:
    key="%s" % (i.split()[0])
    if key in file1:
        output.write(i)
```

Any advice on how to make this code functional? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: first load file1 and put the data in a O(1) lookup (probably set or dictionary), then for each line in file2, (1) split the line on the space, (2) check if first part is in your set/dictionary, (3) if so, write to output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, implement some logic for making all of the numbers in the first file into a set (this code will keep them as strings, not numbers, but that's largely irrelevant):

```
nums = set()
with open("file1.txt") as file1:
    for line in file1:
        nums.add(line.strip())
```

Next, we have the code for filtering each line in the second file. We can output to the final file at the same time, or just store everything temporarily and do it later. This code does it at the same time:

```
with open("file2.txt") as file2, open("output.txt", "wt") as output:
    for line in file2:
        to_check = line.strip().split()[0]
        if to_check in nums:
            print(line.strip(), file=output)
```

And that should do the trick. I've tested it with what you provided and it seems to give the result you wanted, but let me know if it's not doing what you expect.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks a ton for the quick response! The code makes logical sense as well. Thanks again!

Comment: @nrcombs No problem! Would you mind marking this as the correct answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
with open('file1.txt') as f1:
    set1 = [line.strip() for line in f1]

with open('file2.txt') as f2:
    vals = [[val for val in line.split()] for line in f2]

with open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for val in vals:        
        if val[0] in set1:
            fout.write(' '.join(val) + '\n')
```

Read the first file out into a list and the second file into a nested list. Then loop through the file2 values checking if the first entry is in the list from file 1. If you had process many values then you could make `set1` a `set` to improve look up from linear to constant time. For a small number of values it may not be worth the overhead though.

Comment: Excellent, works great. Thanks for the response! Helpful to see the multiple approaches to this task.